# Can't login Ubuntu 16.04 (Gnome) after logout

Tags: keyboard-layout, login-screen, ubuntu-gnome

Problem is that if keyboard layout is set to Russian when screen is locked I can't login using password input field. Only way is to press Switch User and then enter password for my current user.

But if keyboard layout is set to English when screen is locked everything is OK and I can login normally.

Yes, I've checked keyboard layout before entering password.It is set to En. But it makes no sense when I'm trying to change it on locked screen.
I use Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome.

I've checked it on different PCs and on different Virtual machines, the result is the same - can't login when screen is locked with keyboard layout set to Russian and all works normally when it is English or any other English-like keyboard layout. And all woks fine if I press Switch user and log in from start page (the page with password prompt you see when starting PC).

Only idea I have is that language in screen lock don't changes to English from Russian even when you switch manually. How to fix that? Any workarounds of fixes?

Comment: Please show us the output of `cat /etc/default/keyboard`.

Comment: XKBLAYOUT=lv,ru
XKBVARIANT=apostrophe,
BACKSPACE=guess

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue having 2 keyboards English and Arabic on my Ubuntu 18.04.

I switched from LightDM to GDM3 on Ubuntu 18.04 which helped. Now I can switch language from the login screen.

if you don't have GDM3 you can install with

```
sudo apt-get install gdm3
```

to switch from LightDM to GDM3 run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Enter the password if asked then in the dialog click ok and then select GDM3 and press ok again.

Restart the system.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to open `/etc/default/keyboard` for editing and change the lines:

```
XKBLAYOUT=lv,ru
XKBVARIANT=apostrophe,
```

to

```
XKBLAYOUT=lv,ru,us
XKBVARIANT=apostrophe,,
```

After next reboot, that would make the *English (US)* layout available to the login screen, and possibly it makes a difference to the lock screen as well. But I'm not sure of this; your feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this didn't helped. Seems that there is some soft bug in Gnome env, because there were no such problems in Unity.

Comment: @StPavel: Ok, it was a long shot. May be [bug #1652618](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1652618).

Comment: Yes, that's it. I hope that there will be a fix asap.